# Spring Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction. Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven

I'm trying to send my data to a MySql Database but I get this errors. I've tried different formats to write the path to database but none of them seems to work. 
The server on the database is running. 
I also get a

> Bad pool size config, start 3 < min 5. Using 5 as start.

in the console, now sure what that's about.

I have already googled all the errors one by one with no success..

Stack Trace

```
  org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:542)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:377)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:461)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    com.feedback.feed.dao.FeedbackDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1f63c8e.addFeedback(<generated>)
    com.feedback.feed.IndexController.addFeedback(IndexController.java:42)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:109)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:136)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:523)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:448)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:377)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:461)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    com.feedback.feed.dao.FeedbackDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1f63c8e.addFeedback(<generated>)
    com.feedback.feed.IndexController.addFeedback(IndexController.java:42)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:692)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:106)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:136)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:523)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:448)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:377)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:461)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    com.feedback.feed.dao.FeedbackDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1f63c8e.addFeedback(<generated>)
    com.feedback.feed.IndexController.addFeedback(IndexController.java:42)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1469)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:644)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:554)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:758)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:685)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:106)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:136)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:523)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:448)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:377)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:461)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    com.feedback.feed.dao.FeedbackDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1f63c8e.addFeedback(<generated>)
    com.feedback.feed.IndexController.addFeedback(IndexController.java:42)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:207)
    org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
    org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:136)
    org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
    org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
    org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31)
    org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:410)
    org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:280)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
    com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
root cause

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:60)
    org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:101)
    org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
    org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:136)
    org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
    org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
    org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31)
    org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:410)
    org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:280)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
    com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
```

My servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.feedback.feed"></context:component-scan>

    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">

    <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/testone" />

    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />

    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.feedback.feed.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>


<bean id="myTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" /> 



</beans>
```

Pom.xlm

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.feedback</groupId>
  <artifactId>feed</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>feed Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.16.Final</version>
</dependency>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.17.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.6</version>
</dependency>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.5.2</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.17.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
```

Comment: Is your DB running? Does it run on default postgresql port/

Comment: It is running on 3306, which is the default port I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the wrong jdbc url:

```
<property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
<property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/testone" />
```

for Mysql DB, you need to set it to:

```
<property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/testone" />
```

Comment: I have tried this actually and it still gives 

" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection "

but also 

" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver "


is there a problem with my 3cp0?

Comment: I am sure you did not try it yet. Modify your xml and see if it works. MySQL and PostgreSQL are completely different thing.

Comment: My bad, i replied before you wrote the second part. This did it. Such a stupid mistake. Thank you very very much.

Comment: Glad it helped. Cheer :D

Answer (score 0):

This issue could also be related to the version of `mysql-connector-java` specified in your project's dependencies. In my case, when using MySQL server 8.0.32, I encountered a similar problem. Upgrading the `mysql-connector-java` version to 8.0.20 resolved the issue.

You can specify the desired version of `mysql-connector-java` in your project's `pom.xml` (Maven) or `build.gradle` (Gradle).

**For Maven:**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.20</version>
</dependency>
```