# Why Injection of Bean failed in Spring Mvc project

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jaxb

I wanted to follow the tutorial on the following link: [Tutorial Spring MVC](https://o7planning.org/10601/spring-mvc-form-handling-and-hibernate), but at runtime I received the following error message.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'applicantDAOImpl': Injection of autowired
> dependencies failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory
> org.o7planning.springmvcforms.dao.impl.ApplicantDAOImpl.sessionFactory;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in
> org.o7planning.springmvcforms.config.ApplicationContextConfig: Bean
> instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method
> 'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

Does anyone have an idea of the source of this error?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure about the tutorial in the website as it is in French and lots of steps.
You should follow a tutorial which has a workable git repository in Github or Gitlab so that you can simply clone and build. Then after cloning, normally you use Maven or Gradle to the build. This way, you can replicate exactly the same code and library with your tutor.

Try spring boot first, before moving to Spring MVC. You can produce something faster with spring boot. That's my 2 cents.

Comment: @fauzimh, i puted a wrong link, it was corrected. thanks for replying

Comment: Usually, this is a classpath issue. I.e., when you use maven in your project, you are most likely missing a dependency you need. I mostly find those by googling the technologies you use in your project (hibernate in this case), but you could also read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago I've followed that tutorial and it worked for me :)

Based on the exception I would look at the DB configs in your project because it looks like Spring can't create Hibernate-related Beans.
But first I would check some similar problems like your: 
[How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception)

Good luck!

Comment: @Rusian Macari: thanks for you answer, i was using JDK  1.8 to build the project and it seems that javaxb is removed in this version so i aded it but now i get another error "Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection", do you have an idea about this error. thanks

Comment: @DevLearning most likely the problem is related to DB configuration in your project, here is a similar problem and a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775763/spring-could-not-open-hibernate-session-for-transaction-unable-to-acquire-jdbc

Answer (score 0):

Well, i Had Similar Issues with an old project from around 2019 plus

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.ws/jaxws-api -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

i added this dependecy for javax, since it's the one responsible for the xml bindings that may be present in the project.

check here for more explanation https://www.jesperdj.com/2018/09/30/jaxb-on-java-9-10-11-and-beyond/